# dpkg error when trying to install ceph-deploy

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dpkg, ceph

I can't install `ceph-deploy` on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. When I try:

```
apt install ceph-deploy
```

I get this:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ceph-deploy_2.0.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/ceph-deploy.8.gz', which is also in package ceph-base 15.2.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ceph-deploy_2.0.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems to be this bug listed here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ceph/+bug/1892448

Could [this package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ceph/16.2.4-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) solve the problem?

Do I need to install that package? If yes, how do I do that and what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override package installation using low-level command below

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/ceph-deploy_2.0.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

and then run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

to resume package installation.

Comment: thank you! This helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember ceph-deploy is no longer maintained. You can use Cephadm or much more reliable, install ceph cluster the old-school way - command line by command line. This way you do not depend on some wrapper and most important , you start to undestand what you do...

Everting you need to know is here:
https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/install/index_manual/#get-software